# Adding PTT option to android app

Tags: android, sip, voip, rtp

I want to add to sipdroid a push to talk option
I saw the Lumicall open source but I couldn't make it work!!
I have no idea how to start...
I have tried to start with rtp as a regular call but it's have a delay
and I want it to work immediately
I don't know if it's better to work with sipManager?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this projects

https://github.com/good-life/PushTalk

https://code.google.com/p/pttdroid/